# BoUML tool has stopped showing scroll bars on class view

Tags: c++, uml, modeling, class-diagram

I am working with BoUML on an openSUSE machine and I have used the "C++ code reverse" functionallity to obtain the classes form the source code.

Then I have opened a new class diagram in my project and I have started to drag and drop the classes from the classes tree on the left to the diagram on the right.
There are a lot of classes. So, I have increased the diagram size to a personal size (10000 x 14000).

I was working right with this diagram, using the scrolls bars to move up/down and left/right the diagram.  Then I have close BoUML, after saving the project.

When I open this project again, I see all the classes and the class diagram, but he scroll bars are not shown on the class diagram. So, I can only access to the
part of the diagram that correspond to the upper left corner of the sheet.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Best you mail the author. He's here on SO but I haven't seen him for a while.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2458991/bruno is his account here

Comment: Thanks, I will write to him.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I have no problem on a 13.1 I have since long time, before and after updating the packages, and I do not have problem too on a 13.2 (you said me you use a 13.2). I run them under VirtualBox, on a x86-64 processor

Answer (score 1):

On the screenshot you sent me visibly the sub windows of the diagram is larger and higher that the area of the main window dedicated to the diagrams, so of course you do not see the scrollbars of the diagram sub window nor the buttons on its top right allowing to close/expand/iconic it.

Reproducing your case you are like that :
[image]

If I move the diagram sub window to the left its right part including its scrollbar appears :

[image]

Just reduce the size of the diagram sub window to have

[image]

Or expand it using the square button of the sub window :

[image]

It is exactly like if you move the window of an application partially out of your screen or size it larger than your screen, in that case of course you cannot see all of it

---

Out of that on the screenshot you sent me your diagram contains hundreds classes showing their attributes/relations/operations, I cannot understand the goal of that kind of diagram, you cannot read it, there are too many information. I encourage you to reduce the number of classes shown in each diagram and when it is not necessary to hide the attributes/operations (you have several drawing settings). A diagram must have a goal, it must say something, a diagram is not a pile of sand where grains are classes ...

Comment: Wow, impressive answer! by Bruno the author of Bouml himself ?

Comment: @Christophe yes I am, so having 'some' knowledge about BoUML that helped to answer :-)